# Recommendation Based on the Item properties and user preference for item properties

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mahout, mahout-recommender

There is an item , say in travelling domain "Goa" , now here we can have beaches , adventure etc. Now beaches and adventure is property of Goa. Now if a person prefer to travel at locations where there is beaches and also loves adventure. we will recommend "Goa" to him.

My understanding is we need to classify the items and users . set preferences for the item for user. 
I need help on algorithm and steps I should follow as well as if there is some example , which I can follow.